Trying to fit a submodel, What do I do wrong?
lm_full <- lm(CO ~ AT + AP + AH + GTEP + TIT + TAT + TEY, data = Data)
lm_modelA <- lm(CO ~ AT + AP + AH, data = Data)
returns this error message:
i as.data.frame.default(data) :
cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame
What have I missed/done wrong?
I'm a complete newb so my skillset is limited
